# How do return the duplicates in a multi two dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list that is a multi two dimensional list. Basically I would like create a variable with the duplicates in each row and then i would like to create another variable with no duplicates in each row. can this be done by using a list comprehension?

```
df = [[[2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 8, 9, 9],[3, 3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 10, 11],[3, 3, 3, 4, 9, 9, 13, 15]],
      [[2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6],[4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 10],[4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11],[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 11, 12]],
      [[4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11],[3, 3, 3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 11],[3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 12, 12]]]
```

I would like my result to be:

`Dup = [[[3,9],[3, 9],[3, 9]],[[3, 4],[4, 7],[4, 7,[3, 4]],[[7, 11],[3, 11],[3, 7, 12]]]`

`Not in = [[[2 7, 8],[5,10, 11],[4, 13, 15]],[[2, 5, 6],[5,8, 10],[6, 9, 11],[8, 11, 12]],[[4, 6, 9],[5, 9, 10],[6,10]]]`

Comment: `df` is a 3D list...?

Comment: Worked for me actually. Had to re-copy

Comment: Ohh, I see, `df` is a list of 2D lists. This seems like something you could do with `numpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished using list comprehensions and `collections.Counter` as follows:

```
dup = [[[i for i, c in Counter(sl).items() if c>1] for sl in l] for l in df]
not_in = [[[i for i, c in Counter(sl).items() if c==1] for sl in l] for l in df]
```

Just fyi I used `l` and `sl` the lists and sublists accordingly. `i` stands for item and `c` is the count of that item in `sl`. Results are as follows:

```
#duplicates
[[[3, 9], [3, 9], [3, 9]], [[3, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [3, 4]], [[7, 11], [3, 11], [3, 7, 12]]]
#uniques
[[[2, 7, 8], [5, 10, 11], [4, 13, 15]], [[2, 5, 6], [5, 8, 10],[6, 9, 11], [8, 11, 12]], [[4, 6, 9], [5, 9, 10], [6, 10]]]
```

Comment: You are flattening the list of lists of lists to a list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

Without additional imports, just using a doubly-nested list comprehension, `set`, and `count`:

```
>>> [[[x for x in set(ll) if ll.count(x) > 1] for ll in l] for l in df]
[[[3, 9], [3, 9], [3, 9]],
 [[3, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [3, 4]],
 [[7, 11], [3, 11], [3, 7, 12]]]

>>> [[[x for x in set(ll) if ll.count(x) == 1] for ll in l] for l in df]
[[[2, 7, 8], [5, 10, 11], [4, 13, 15]],
 [[2, 5, 6], [5, 8, 10], [6, 9, 11], [8, 11, 12]],
 [[4, 6, 9], [5, 9, 10], [6, 10]]]
```

Note, though, that using [`Counter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58170979/1639625) might be faster if the inner-most lists are very large; otherwise it should not matter, and this version might be the most straight-forward and easy-to-read.

Comment: You're right, this is faster than mine just didn't even think of that. Nice answer.

Comment: @Jab Hm, I wouldn't think that it's faster if the lists are very large, as this would have complexity of O(n²) (n being the average length of the innermost list), while yours should be O(n). But creating the `Counter` might have some overhead making it slower for many short lists.

Comment: Well I was refering to OPs case but yes agreed.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dup = [[list(dict.fromkeys([el for i, el in zip(range(len(l)), l) if el in l[:i]+l[i+1:]])) for l in ll] for ll in df]
Not_in = [[[el for i, el in zip(range(len(l)), l) if el not in l[:i]+l[i+1:]] for l in ll] for ll in df]
```